# How do change the font size and font color from a Java file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I change the font color, size and button color from a Java file in Eclipse, not from an XML file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For font size you can write it as

```
tv.setTextSize(20.0f);
```

For font color you can write it as

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

For button background color you can write it as

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
```

Comment: can i use the same code for spinner ??? It is working fine for button but not for spinner as i think the spinner's text is changeable and changes after selection .i hope u understand what i want to say...

Comment: well have a look at this... i just googled and i found this... I think it is possible to change for spinner items too. Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989817/set-the-textsize-to-a-text-in-spinner-in-android-programatically

Answer (score 5):

```
button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: can i use the same code for spinner ??? It is working fine for button but not for spinner as i think the spinner's text is changeable and changes after selection .i hope u understand what i want to say...

Comment: You can refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880413/text-color-of-a-closed-spinner

Answer (score 2):

In the "`Inherited XML Attributes`" paragraph of [the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) you can see either XML attributes (that you can change from XML) or related methods (which you can use in your Java code).

Answer (score 1):

Others already posted answers on how to do it in Java, but I guess these could help you as well.

How to do it in XML:

- [Font Styling](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)
- [Button Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color) --Link changed.