# Text Size for Different Resolution Density Just Using XML

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How do we change the textSize based on Resolution density?

I have found several ways on SO, but all of them usng java code to do that.

I however need a java free approach because I have someplaces where I set a textSize on XML and some on Java code.

In xml, I do this

```
        android:textSize="@dimen/FONT_SIZE_SMALL"
```

however sometimes I need to set it via java code.

```
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.FONT_SIZE_SMALL);
```

Any ideas please?  is it doable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/drawable-folder-for-different-resolution-and-application-icon-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text size with different resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620343/text-size-with-different-resolution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `textSize` in `sp` unit in xml. It will adjust to all resolutions.

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**
Please also refer to [Text size with different resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620343/text-size-with-different-resolution) which proposes some scaling factors for different resolutions.

Comment: Yes, that is what I have been doing

Comment: That should suffice your needs. What else do you need?

Comment: Doesn't this fulfill your need?

Comment: @MustansarSaeed No, cause sometimes I had to use Java when setting text Size. (i.e.: When I request data from server). I have edited the question

Comment: @Anirudh  Sometimes I had to use Java when setting text Size. (i.e.: When I request data from server). That would cause the solution presented by Mustansar unusable

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157069/how-to-change-the-font-size-and-font-color-from-the-java-file

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Are you using single layout file or different for different DPIs?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare sizes with the `<dimen>` tag in dimens.xml in resolution specific values folder.
eg

```
<dimen name="my_text_view_size">12sp</dimen>
```

You can have multiple value files for different resolutions and can assign different values for the same constant for each resolution. then assign the constant to textsize.

check this for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16910589/3329488